# Adobe CSDK editor is not showing stickers, overlays and frames, getting error

Tags: jquery, adobecreativesdk

I've integrated Adobe CSDK editor in my web application and used API key given in an example, but now stickers, overlays and frames are not working.

I'm gettimg below errors:

1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 
   (Service Unavailable)
2) Error getting assets. Please check your authentication parameters.

See below screenshot for your reference.

[image: image for editor error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stickers, overlays, and frames were end-of-life'd on 11/30/2018. I'm going to paste in the announcement we emailed to Creative CSDK users below:

> End of Support for the Image Editor on November 30th, 2018
>
> As we announced last year, we are ending support for the Image Editor component in the Creative SDK. If you haven’t already, we recommend that you remove the Image Editor UI from your web or mobile applications as soon as possible to avoid further disruption to the user experience in your application.
>
> Core services for the Image Editor UI will be shut off on Friday, 11/30. This means that the Image Editor will stop working for Web integrations and distribution of content (effects, frames, overlays, and stickers) will stop for iOS and Android integrations.
>
> The Color UI, Market Browser, and Labs components may continue to function, but they are also deprecated and no longer supported.
>
> You can find the End of Support Announcement [here](https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004788463-End-of-Support-for-the-Creative-SDK-Image-Editor-UI-Color-UI-Market-Browser-and-Labs-Components) and an [FAQ here](https://creativesdk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004788243-Creative-SDK-Image-Editor-UI-Color-UI-Market-Browser-Labs-Component-Deprecation-FAQ).

I ran this email campaign myself, so I know many of the email addresses were old (plus if you opted out of communications, you wouldn't have gotten it). I wish I could suggest another Adobe product to use instead, but at the moment no such products are available.